# Java parsing many instances of substring from String

Tags: java, substring, java.util.scanner

I am trying to write a small java program that will accept a file (using Scanner class), return the file as a String, and then search that string for any instance of a substring starting with "Email:" and ending with ".edu". There will be many instances of this substring, each of which I want to parse out into an array or a new file.

I know how to find a substring, but I do not know how to A) search for all instances of the substring and B) specify the start AND finish of the substring.

Can someone help me with this logic?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a case for regular expressions to me:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Test
{
    private static final Pattern EMAIL_PATTERN = Pattern.compile
        ("Email:(.*?\\.edu)");

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String testString = "FooEmail:jjj@xyz.edu Bar Email:mmm@abc.edu Baz";

        printEmails(testString);
    }

    public static void printEmails(String input)
    {
        Matcher matcher = EMAIL_PATTERN.matcher(input);
        while (matcher.find())
        {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you'll get strange results if you have any *non* `.edu` emails in there... for example, if you have "Email: foo@bar.com Email: a@b.edu" you'd end up with a match of "foo@bar.com Email: a@b.edu".

Comment: This is very helpful to me, thank you! I'm going to have to learn more about regular expressions - they seem like they can do powerful things!

Comment: @behrk2: Regular expressions are great in their place - which is pattern matching. They can easily be overused though. In this case they're a good fit, but don't try to use them for *all* string manipulation tasks... there are often simpler ways.

Comment: Stand back, I know regular exceptions !

Comment: If there is always a space between two email addresses, you could prevent the problem noted in the last sentence by modifying the regular expression to `Email:(\\S+\\.edu)`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use indexOf(). I think you can tell it where to search from too. So to find your instances of "Email:":

```
while(index < input.size()){
  substringLocation = input.indexOf("Email:", index);
  // do something with substring
  index = substringLocation;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private static final Pattern EMAIL_PATTERN = Pattern.compile
    ("Email:(.*?\\.[a-z]*?[\\.[a-z]]*)");
```

Will solve the problem and itt will work for any email pattern such as abc.co.in xyz.com  or test.fileserver.abc.co.bz domains.